# ReportViewer did not display data

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have tried to add report using ReportViewer in Visual Studio 2012, SQL Server 2005. I am using Visual Basic Language.

So far I've tried this code and did not show the data I wanted

```
Imports Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim rds As New ReportDataSource("DataSet1")

    Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "C:\Users\acer\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\Report1.rdlc"
    Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
    Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds)
    Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
End Sub
End Class
```

Can anybody show me how to fix this? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supossing that your DataSet contains one or more DataTables, you're missing the DataTable which you want to show on the report.

```
Dim rds As New ReportDataSource("DataSet1", ds.Tables(0))
```

From what I see in your code, you don't have any DataTable neither any source where you're retrieving data from.
The below code shows how to retrieve data from a database table and display it onto your ReportViewer

```
Dim strConnectionString As String = "Your connection string here"
Dim ds As New DataSet()
Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter()
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM YourTable")
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
cmd.Connection = New SqlConnection(strConnectionString)
da.SelectCommand = cmd

da.Fill(ds, "DataSet1")

Dim rds As New ReportDataSource("DataSet1", ds.Tables(0))

Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "C:\Users\acer\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\Report1.rdlc"
Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds)
Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
```

Comment: My bad didn't code the dataTable. Now it shows the data. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Again Configuration of Datasource and reportview .Firstly go to ADD Datasoure then select database then click the next then select dataset then click next again next 
then check both tables and **Views**  then Finish ... then select report view then click new design  then finish then choose report then hope so [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20iqi.jpg)